# How to remove index.php from Yii URLs in Apache/Centos?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I am working with ***Yii Framework*** on ***Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server***.

Following line is uncommented in ***/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf***

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I can see **mod_rewrite** under **Loaded Module** when I do following

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

**Yii Project Structure:**

```
/var/www/test/ 
/var/www/test/index.php 
/var/www/test/.htaccess
```

**.htaccess content**

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**It works fine when I do:**

```
http://10.20.30.40/test/index.php/testcontroller/testaction
```

**But when I do:**

```
http://10.20.30.40/test/testcontroller/testaction
```

**It shows following error:**

```
Not Found

The requested URL /var/www/test/index.php was not found on this server.
```

Any idea?

Comment: @Awan have you solved this problem? I have having same issue, please help me if you have solved it. Thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same trouble.
I use Apache config alias, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...

Alias /project "/Users/foo/Sites/project"

...
</VirtualHost>
```

To solve, I use "RewriteBase" directive on .htaccess, example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project # <---- Modify here! and remove this comment.

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/#c9725

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

htaccess content.

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'),
```

urlmanager config in your main.php. Or you can customize it if you want.

Comment: Read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url topic. It will be usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that AllowOverride is "All" for your project's web directory in httpd.conf. If not, change the value and restart the web server

Answer (score 0):

I solved this editing the Apache Configuration file at:

`{{ApacheDir}}/conf/httpd.conf`

And Un-commenting / Adding the following line:

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`